# How to compare input date is less than two months old or greater than today's date

Tags: jquery

In Jquery, I want to throw an error when the input date is less than two months old or is greater than  today's date. I start to compare two months old date first. Input date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

I did as below, but it's not working

```
var tbStartDate = "07/05/2017";
      var twoMonthsOldDate = new Date();
                        twoMonthsOldDate = new Date(twoMonthsOldDate .setMonth(twoMonthsOldDate .getMonth() - 2));
                        alert(twoMonthsOldDate );
                        alert(tbStartDate);
                        if (tbStartDate < twoMonthsOldDate) {
                            alert('is less');
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var tbStartDate = new Date("07/05/2017").getTime() / 1000;
      var twoMonthsOldDate = new Date();
                        twoMonthsOldDate = new Date(twoMonthsOldDate.setMonth(twoMonthsOldDate.getMonth() - 2)).getTime() / 1000;
                        console.log(twoMonthsOldDate );
                        console.log(tbStartDate);
                        if (tbStartDate < twoMonthsOldDate) {
                            alert('is less');
                        }
```

Basically, I converted your dates to epoch so I can compare them. As you had it, they were different formats, so you couldn't effectively compare.

Now, you could include a library called moment.js, and trim it down and make it a bit more readable.

```
var tbStartDate = moment("02/05/2017");
      var twoMonthsOldDate = moment().subtract(2, 'month');
                        if (twoMonthsOldDate.isAfter(tbStartDate)) {
                            alert('is less');
                        }
```

Comment: I did as you said, but it does not throw alert if input is less than two months old. I do not need to compare times and date is in (dd/mm/yyyy format) var inputDate = new Date(tbStartDate).getTime() / 1000;                
                var twoMonthsOldDate = new Date();
                twoMonthsOldDate = new Date(twoMonthsOldDate.setMonth(twoMonthsOldDate.getMonth() - 2)).getTime() / 1000;                
                if (inputDate < twoMonthsOldDate) {
                    alert('is less');
                }

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
<script>

var inputDate = new Date('05/04/2017');
var today = new Date();
var m2_old = new Date();

m2_old = new Date(m2_old.setMonth(m2_old.getMonth()-2));

if(inputDate > today) {
   console.log(inputDate," is greater than today ..."); 
} else if(inputDate > m2_old) {
    console.log(inputDate," is less than two months old ...");
} else {
   console.log(inputDate," is older or equal than two months...");
}


</script>
```